# Getting error when creating an order from Magento admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I found my problem in Stack Overflow and I got some solution [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509570/magento-checkout-place-order-ajax-500-internal-server-error), but it is not working in my case.

When I place order from my Magento store (front-end) it's working completely: all steps from login to placing an order, all is good, and even I get order in Magento back-end and I can do anything for that order (hold, processing, pending, complete).

But when I try to create order from Magento back-end I can not get delivery methods (shipping methods) and it is showing me error in my console.

My error in console is

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded [http://test.diydoctor.bathcomms.com/index.php/diydoctor_admin/sales_order_create/loadBlock/key/d534b4a174d425d986cad5b8a282d0ad/block/shipping_method,totals?isAjax=true"](http://test.diydoctor.bathcomms.com/index.php/diydoctor_admin/sales_order_create/loadBlock/key/d534b4a174d425d986cad5b8a282d0ad/block/shipping_method,totals?isAjax=true%22) with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Is it server issue or AJAX calling issue or anything else?

I also attach image with error:

[image]

How can I find a solution for my problem?

Comment: Have you taken a look at your server error logs? Apache/Nginx? As this is a 500 error, it's likely you'll find the answer there

Comment: @DouglasRadburn I don't have access for server so can't check server logs.any other solutions?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  You need access to those logs.  Perhaps you can ask your hosts nicely to supply them? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I think this might be on-topic for here, in the sense that programming is involved, but it is lacking a [mcve]. I have cast a close vote of that type.